# For loop to iterate through pattern matched column in data frame and produce ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the sample data below, I'd like to iterate through the columns in my data frame to produce a ggplot, but I'm struggling to get the logic right (I'm new to R). I want to iterate through only the columns with the phrase "percent" in them.

This is an example of when I'm generating a single ggplot on one column:

```
ggwatched10percent = ggplot(data = df1, aes(x=Duration, y=watched10percent))
ggwatched10percent + geom_point(aes(colour=factor(Content))) + ggtitle("Duration / viewed10percent Viewed")
ggsave(file.path('graphs', 'watched10percent.pdf'))
```

I'm looking for a for loop that will, considering the data below, iterate through the watched10percent, watched50percent and watched100percent columns (in each iteration the Duration and Content columns will always be utilised).

The given column will be used as the y value. I also need the given column to be used as the filename in ggsave, used on the chart title and maybe as the variable for the graph (e.g. ggwatched10ercent) - although I'd be happy with an incrementing number for this.

Sample data:

```
Content <- c('Part1','Part2','Part3')
Duration <- c(102, 205, 167)
watched10percent <- c('76','72','81')
watched50percent <- c('54','58','72')
watched100percent <- c('37','31','68')

df1 <- data.frame(Content, Duration, watched10percent, watched50percent, watched100percent)
```

Edit - I have removed my data samples provided... the errors I was getting was because my data wasn't aggregated, but once it was, the answer provided worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.

If you wish to use a `for` loop, you can look at column names that contain "percent".

You y-axis can reference `.data[[wp]]` to extract the appropriate data from the column name.

You can integrate the column name in your title in a number of ways. The final `ggsave` can also use the column name for the .pdf file.

```
library(ggplot2)

for (wp in names(df1)[grepl("percent", names(df1))]) {
  ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = Duration, y = .data[[wp]])) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = factor(Content))) + 
    ggtitle(paste("Duration /", wp, "Viewed"))
            
  ggsave(file.path('graphs', paste0(wp, '.pdf')))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I'm getting the following error: 
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (65): x
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: It was the latter, and I have added my actual data to the bottom of my post.

Comment: I've added my full set of data - I believe the causes might be, that Content isn't unique, and therefore needs to be aggregated (using mean)... that's just my guess though. The duration will be the same (e.g. Content 1.1. will always have a duration of 99, but the % viewed columns will differ)

Comment: I aggregated my data, and it worked! Thank you for your help